# Expansion of [help/mcve]

Tags: feature-request

Can we use `[help/mcve]` in the same way we can use `[help/dont-ask]`? The MCVE page seems to be the only one of the commonly used pages without a shorthand code.

Comment: I believe the reason it doesn't have its own magic link (yet) is because it's a custom help page that was made for Stack Overflow (I'm not sure if any other site has it).

Comment: see [help/dontask] ...  Hmm, doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: [ask] [answer] [dont-ask]

Comment: Which one works for dontask?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry - a typo. Should have been `[help/dont-ask]`, which does work here. Fixed in question.

Comment: At [pt.so] we also have this help page. So, if this is rolled to SO, please remember SOPT.